# Possible Choices for u and dv in integration by parts

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Let us have an integral (In)

$$\int x \cos(x) \, dx $$

We get 8 combinations for u and dv, in order to integrate the given integral by parts, as follows

1- u=1, dv=x cosx dx

2- u=x cosx, dv= dx

3- u=x cosx dx, dv=1

4- u=x dx, dv= cosx

5- u= cosx dx, dv= x

6- u=x, dv=cosx dx

7- u= cosx, dv= x dx

8- u= dx, dv= x cosx

But according to my book, we have only 4 of these combinations valid, which are 1, 2, 6 and 7.

Idk what is the reason behind eliminitating 3, 4, 5 and 8.

*what is the reason behind eliminating the combination 3, 4, 5 and 8? Why are these combinations not valid for 'integration by parts'*

Comment: a solution in the known elementary functions isn't possible

Comment: Any example? Explanation pls? Cuz I don't get you @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: do you mean $$\int \ln(x\cos(x))dx$$

Comment: No, Sir. In stands for Integral Idk Latex. @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: aha so it is $$\int x\cos(x)dx$$

Comment: Yes sir @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: Sir can you tell me just one thing. Maybe it will solve my issue. in my given integral, is dx a constant or it can vary with the two functions x and cosx? Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: Explanation A is correct.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can set $u=x$ and $v'=\cos(x)$ then you will get $$u'=1$$ and $$v=\sin(x)$$
and our integral will be
$$x\sin(x)-\int \sin(x)dx$$

Comment: Sir can you tell me just one thing. Maybe it will solve my issue. in my given integral, is dx a constant or it can vary with the two functions x and cosx? Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: no $dx$ is a differential and Shows us for what variable we will integrate

Comment: can you solve your Problem now?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: @amWhy is correct somehow. This answer is not relatable.

Comment: @amWhy can you please give me the answer cuz I think you have got my problem.